# How can I add current class to a clicked element and removing it when clicking on another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not very good at JavaScript and most of the time I use other people's work. I want to know how I can add a current class to the following code so that I can make changes to selected element.
Thanks

```js
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
  $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
      $(this).show(200);
    } else {
      $(this).hide(600);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<a href="javascript:showonlyone(&#39;link1&#39;);">
  <div>
    <p>link1</p>
  </div>
</a>
<div class="newboxes" id="link1" style="display: none">
  <p>Content1</p>
</div>


<a href="javascript:showonlyone(&#39;link2&#39;);">
  <div>
    <p>link2</p>
  </div>
</a>
<div class="newboxes" id="link2" style="display: none">
  <p>Content2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "current class"?

Comment: Something like this:

$(this).addClass('current')

Comment: And why can't you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
$(this).addClass('current-class');
```

and remove with

```
$(this).removeClass('current-class');
```

```js
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {

     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(200);
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(600);
          }
     });
     
     $('.link').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).text() == thechosenone) {
               $(this).addClass('current');
          }
          else {
               $(this).removeClass('current');
          }
     });
}
```

```css
.current {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<a href="javascript:showonlyone(&#39;link1&#39;);"><div><p class='link'>link1</p></div>
</a>
<div class="newboxes" id="link1" style="display: none">
<p>Content1</p>
</div>


<a href="javascript:showonlyone(&#39;link2&#39;);"><div><p class='link'>link2</p></div>
</a>
<div class="newboxes" id="link2" style="display: none">
<p>Content2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats great! It adds the current class to the content class but I am trying to add the current class to the actual link like adding border around the clicked link which in this case is "link1". Sorry it was my mistake not clearly delivering my question.
Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use addClass and removeClass as below:

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(200);
               $(this).addClass("current");
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(600);
               $(this).removeClass("current");
          }
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it adds the class to the content not the link. Is there any way to add the class to the link? like adding a border around "link1" when it is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

As per your Q - *clicked element and removing it when clicking on another element?*

you will have to use `$('yourEl').removeClass('ClassRemove');` first then `$(this).addClass('ClassRemove');`, so that all the class which name `yourEl` will be removed the class `ClassRemove` and only the element you click will be added with the Class `ClassRemove`

But as you have an `if condition` for that so there is no need to use `$('yourEl').removeClass('ClassRemove')`. I have updated the code as per your comment.

```js
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(200);
               $(this).prev('a').addClass('current');
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(600);
               $(this).prev('a').removeClass('current');
          }
     });
}
```

```css
a p{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.current{
  border:1px #000 solid;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<a href="javascript:showonlyone(&#39;link1&#39;);"><div><p>link1</p></div>
</a>
<div class="newboxes" id="link1" style="display: none">
<p>Content1</p>
</div>


<a href="javascript:showonlyone(&#39;link2&#39;);"><div><p>link2</p></div>
</a>
<div class="newboxes" id="link2" style="display: none">
<p>Content2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation. It works perfectly with the content part. What should I do to have the current class in the link so that I could add like a border around it when it is clicked?

Comment: @MustafaHaidari, I have updated the code for you. if its works for you mark it as the answer.ty

Comment: MustafaHaidari Yw, as per me your single condition in enough to manage the function not need for 2 `.each` loop to work for this simple function as per the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've reorganized your code a bit to make it easier to use jQuery selectors to do what you want.

**Version 1: Highlight link**

```js
function highlightLink(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var $otherParents = $(this)
    .parent()
    .siblings(".newbox_parent");

  $otherParents.children(".newboxes").hide(600);
  $otherParents.children("a").removeClass("current");

  $(this).siblings(".newboxes").show(200);
  $(this).children("p").addClass("current");
}

$(".newbox_parent > a").click(highlightLink);
```

```css
.current {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="newbox_parent">
  <a href="#">
    <p>link1</p>
  </a>
  <div class="newboxes" style="display: none">
    <p>Content1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="newbox_parent">
  <a href="#">
    <p>link2</p>
  </a>
  <div class="newboxes" style="display: none">
    <p>Content2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Version 2: Highlight container**

```js
function highlightLink(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var $parent = $(this)
    .parent()
    .addClass("current")
    .siblings(".newbox_parent")
    .removeClass("current")
    .children(".newboxes")
    .hide(600);

  $(this).siblings(".newboxes").show(200);
}

$(".newbox_parent > a").click(highlightLink);
```

```css
.current {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="newbox_parent">
  <a href="#">
    <p>link1</p>
  </a>
  <div class="newboxes" style="display: none">
    <p>Content1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="newbox_parent">
  <a href="#">
    <p>link2</p>
  </a>
  <div class="newboxes" style="display: none">
    <p>Content2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)